# Laravel custom paginate not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am having a problem in pagination on laravel.

This was working before with no problem.

```
$users = user::getAllUsers()->paginate(10);
```

But I need to change the code therefore the only way is to use the custom pagination

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

public function companies()
{
     $users = user::getAllUsers()->get(//some codes here);
     $paginated = = new Paginator($users , 2);

     $paginated ->setPath('/users/view');
     return view('users.view', compact('paginated'));
}
```

The problem with the 2nd code is that when I am pressing the next button to redirect to page=2, the values in the view is not changing. the url is changing though.

Not sure if I am missing something here. Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use** LengthAwarePaginator

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function companies(Request $request){
    ...
    $items_per_page = 2;
    $paginated = new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $users->forPage($request->page ?: 1, $items_per_page),
        $users->count(),
        $items_per_page
    );
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting a "Undefined variable: request " error

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte see updated answer. Alternatively you may use Input::get('page') instead of $request->page, but using the Request is recommended (for larval 5.x )

Comment: Thanks man this solved my problem.
May I also ask how do you set a path for this?
What happens now is that it redirects to the base url (localhost:8000?page=2), but I need it to go to localhost:8000\users\view?page=2

Comment: got it. I put back my $paginated ->setPath('/users/view');
Thanks man big help. Cheers :)

Comment: You don't need to set a path for this, by default it will send back to the same url with new page number in GET parameters

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as the third parameter

```
$paginated = new Paginator($users , 2, $request->get('page'));
```

Parameters are in the order: items, perPage, currentPage

Comment: I am getting a "Undefined variable: request " error

Comment: $request you can inject in controller function.